# How to pass dynamic parameter to select statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query in MySQL:

```
select id, 1 from table;
```

When I run this query I will get the result as below

```
id   | 1
-----|----
5001 | 1 
5002 | 1 
5003 | 1
```

Here I'm passing static value as a parameter to the SQL query. 
In Place of static value I have a list like

```
A = [1,2,3]
```

Size of A is same as the number of rows in the table.

List elements may not be in the incremental order they may be in any random order elements may have strings also but we will have a list.

I want replace static parameter with A. So that it will iterate with list and gives the list elements

I need a query which does like below
for example :

```
select id , A from table;
```

Result :

```
id  | A 
----|-----
5001| 1 
5002| 2 
5003| 3
```

Can someone help me in generating this query?

Comment: is `1,2,3` are always incremental order ?

Comment: No, they may be any random things like strings or integers anything. But it is a list

Comment: You can do it using procedures, if you are willing to.

Comment: I'm willing to use only queries not procedures @AlekhyaVemavarapu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql> select id from new_table;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @row_number = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, @row_number := @row_number + 1, ELT(@row_number, '1111', 2222) AS A from new_table;
+----+--------------------------------+------+
| id | @row_number := @row_number + 1 | A    |
+----+--------------------------------+------+
|  1 |                              1 | 1111 |
|  2 |                              2 | 2222 |
+----+--------------------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```